# Let $X ,Y \subseteq \Bbb R$ . Define $X + Y = \{x + y : x \in X, y \in Y\}$. If $X$ and $Y$ are closed s.t. $X$ is compact then $X + Y$ is closed

Tags: general-topology

Let $X ,Y \subseteq \Bbb R$ . Define $X + Y = \{x + y : x \in X, y \in Y\}$. If $X$ and $Y$ are closed such that $X$ is compact then prove that $X + Y$ is closed?

My Attempt:

Case 1, Let $x \in X$ then $X + Y = \cup_x (x + Y)$

Case 2,  let $y \in Y$ then $X + Y = \cup_y (X + y)$

In both cases, $X + Y$ is arbitrary Union of closed sets which is not closed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $(z_n)$ be a sequence in $X+Y$ conveging to $z$.  Write $z_n=x_n+y_n$ with $x_n \in X$ and $y_n \in Y$. By compactness there is a subsequence $(x_{n_k})$ of $(x_n)$ converging to some point $x \in X$. Now $x_{n_k}+y_{n_k}=z_{n_k}$. Hence $y_{n_k} \to z-x$. Let $y=z-x$. Then $y \in Y$ because $Y$ is closed.  We now get $z=x+y$. So $z \in X+Y$ proving that $X+Y$ is closed.

Comment: Thank you for a nice solution. Why you said that $(y_{n_k}) \to y$

Comment: @SangamAcademy $y_{n_k}=z_{n_k}-x_{n_k}$, $x_{n_k} \to x$  and $z_{n_k} \to z$. So  $y_{n_k} \to z-x$.

Answer (score 0):

Another proof: we see that $\{x + y | x \in X, y \in Y\}$'s complement is $V = \{z \in \mathbb{R} | \forall x \in X, z - x \notin Y\}$. Let $U$ be the open set $\{x \in \mathbb{R} | x \notin Y\}$. Then $V = \{z \in \mathbb{R} | \forall x \in X, x \in f_z^{-1}(U)\} = \{z \in \mathbb{R} | X \subseteq f_z^{-1}(U)\}$, where $f_z(x) = z - x$.

Now fix some $z \in V$. Then since $X$ is compact and $f_z^{-1}(U)$ is open, there is some $\epsilon > 0$ such that for all $x \in X$, $B_\epsilon(x) \subseteq f^{-1}(U)$. Then take some $y \in B_\epsilon(z)$. Then for all $x \in X$, $y - x = (y - z) + (z - x) = z - (x + (y - z))$. And $x - (y - z) \in B_\epsilon(x) \subseteq f_z^{-1}(U)$, so $f_z(x - (y - z)) = z - (x + (y - z)) = y - x \in U$. Then $y \in V$.

This shows that $B_\epsilon(z) \subseteq V$. So $V$ is open. Then $\{x + y | x \in X, y \in Y\}$ is closed.